# i get an error "expression can't be used as a function "

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    float x;
    float y;
    cin >> x;
    y = (7*((x-3)^2)-6(x-4)+5) ;
    cout<<y;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this keep giving me error "expression can't be used as a function " ?

Comment: incidentally, `^2` doesn't mean what you think it does. It's the [bitwise XOR operator.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a syntax issue:

```
y = (7*((x-3)^2)-6(x-4)+5) ;
                 ^
```

You need to explicitly multiply otherwise it looks like you are trying to call the function `6`:

```
y = (7*((x-3)^2)-6*(x-4)+5) ;
```

Then you will need to deal with the error that results from trying to do a bitwise XOR (the `^` operator is bitwise XOR) with a `float` and an `int`.

```
test.cpp:9:19: error: invalid operands of types ‘float’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator^’
```

If you instead meant to use a power you will need to do that differently. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

Answer (score 1):

this expression:

```
6(x-4)
```

means call function for `6` with argument (x-4), hense the error because `6` is obviously not a function. C++ is not math you cannot omit multiplication.

Comment: If you believe in an [april joke](http://www.stroustrup.com/whitespace98.pdf), it will be possible to write C++ like that one day

Answer (score 0):

you need to

```
#include <cmath> or <math.h>
```

if you want to raise to power. you need to use the pow function.

```
pow((x-3),2)
```